# Update value NULL with php in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have this query:

```
UPDATE `terms` 
   SET id = '15',
       taxonomy_id = '1',
       parent_id = NULL,
       level = 0,
       position = 1,
       active = '1',
       time_created = '2012-05-24 09:31:12',
       time_updated = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
 WHERE id = 15
```

And I want to set the parent_id to NULL with php, but how do I do this?
These are wrong:

`$term->parent_id = 'NULL';` -> this is a string
`$term->parent_id = NULL;` -> this is empty
`$term->parent_id = 0;` -> this is an integer

Comment: What's in between the PHP code and the database? i.e. how are these values interpolated?

Comment: what wrong with your query? `parent_id = NULL` will update the field into null.

Comment: the query is correct, but I want to set the value with a variable, the code between is not that simple, it's build with classes

Comment: @Ruben: Raw PHP won't give you that level of abstraction you seem to be using. We need more details on what you actually use to actually help you.

Comment: ok, I think something goes wrong in my database class, I'll check that out first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a problem in my database class, that's why my parent_id value was always empty
this is how I fixed it:

old code:

```
public function set($data)
    {
        $this->query .= ' SET ';

        if(is_object($data))
            $data = get_object_vars($data);

        if(is_array($data))
        {
            $l = count($data);
            $t = 1;
            foreach($data as $k => $v)
            {
                $this->query .= $k . ' = ' . ((is_string($v)) ? '\'' . $this->_escape($v) . '\'' : $this->_escape($v));
                if($t < $l)
                    $this->query .= ',';
                $t++;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $this->query .= $data;
        }


        return $this;
    }
```

new code:

```
public function set($data)
    {
        $this->query .= ' SET ';

        if(is_object($data))
            $data = get_object_vars($data);

        if(is_array($data))
        {
            $l = count($data);
            $t = 1;
            foreach($data as $k => $v)
            {
                $this->query .= $k . ' = ';
                if(is_string($v))
                {
                    $this->query .= '\'' . $this->_escape($v) . '\'';
                } elseif (is_null($v)) {
                    $this->query .= 'NULL';

                } else {
                    $this->query .= $this->_escape($v);
                }

                if($t < $l)
                    $this->query .= ',';

                $t++;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $this->query .= $data;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query should be as :**

some query editors requires NULL as null

```
UPDATE `terms` SET 
    id = '15',
    taxonomy_id = '1',
    parent_id = null,
    level = 0,
    position = 1,
    active = '1',
    time_created = '2012-05-24 09:31:12',
    time_updated = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
WHERE 
    id = 15
```

Comment: what's the difference between `NULL` and `null`?

Comment: @johntotetwoo it depends on his query editor `MySQL Query Browser` takes as simple null

Comment: @Sudantha sql is case insensitive language. How do u say that query editors requires NULL as null?

Comment: @Prathap yes you are correct its not about SQL im talking about how query editor interprets that

Comment: @Sudantha may I know some query editor that looks for case sensitive like null as NULL. It will be gud to know...